# How to define the correct interface and loop over the data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am kinda new to Typescript. Here I have a simple API, and I want to iterate through, and display the data. You can go to the API link and see the raw data. I would be really grateful for some help.

**Interfaces:**

```
export interface ITrending {
  coins: IItem[]
}

export interface IItem {
  item: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    symbol: string;
    market_cap_rank: number;
    thumb?: string;
    large?: string
  } 
}
```

**React Code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { ITrending } from '../interfaces'
const TRENDING = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending'
const Home = () => {
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState<ITrending[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<ITrending[]>(TRENDING).then((response) => {
      setTrending(response.data)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  return <div></div>
}

export default Home
```

**Sample API response:**

```json
{
   "coins":[
      {
         "item":{
            "id":"superfarm",
            "name":"SuperFarm",
            "symbol":"SUPER",
            "market_cap_rank":235,
            "thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/thumb/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "large":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/14040/large/6YPdWn6.png?1613975899",
            "score":0
         }
      },
      {...}
   ],
   "exchanges":[]
}
```

Comment: Going thru an array of data in TypeScript is as easy as using JavaScript. Use `.map`. A simple exmaple `trending.map((item) => // your logic here // )` after the `=>` you can add `{ //logic here // }` but then you require a `return` inside of it.

Comment: Still can't see data being displayed in the console

Comment: @Ajeet Shah is the fetch good bcs I cant see any data displaying in the console

Comment: Try `axios.get<ITrending[]>(TRENDING).then((response) => { setTrending(response.data); console.log(response) }).catch(err => { console.log(err); })`. Have you really solved CORS?

Comment: Instead of trending it should be an <Item[]> with the question below, is it?

Comment: `axios.get<ResponseObject>( ... `

Comment: tried, getting error ```cant find name response did you mean Response``` on the attempt to iterate data

Comment: try changing the `setTrending(response.data)` to `setTrending([...response.data])`. And the `.map` on ur `trending` should work fine as mentioned as long as you actually fetch the data. If the `console.log()` is not being triggered in the `.then` then something is up. Include the `.catch` block and print out the error. If something, anything is not working - u should have some sort of an error that you are not providing in the post.

Comment: also, try prinnting out just the `response` itself `console.log(response)` in the `.then` to make sure the structure is what u actually have. It could be that `response.data` dosent even exist.

Comment: @Lilith ok I am getting the data in the console, but how to iterate it

Answer (score 0):

As the coins are inside of `data.coins`, you need to have it this way:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { ITrending } from '../interfaces'
const TRENDING = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search/trending'
const Home = () => {
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState<ITrending[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<ITrending[]>(TRENDING).then((response) => {
      setTrending(response.data.coins)
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  return <div>{trending.map(t => (<div key={t.item.id}>{t.item.name}</div>)}</div>
}

export default Home
```

Comment: I am getting item does not exist in Trending property